# Enforcing Git branch name policy: difference beween git-apply and git-merge directories

Tags: git, branch, commit, policy

I want to enforce a policy for Git branch names.  Based on the code [here](https://itnext.io/using-git-hooks-to-enforce-branch-naming-policy-ffd81fa01e5e), I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# Enforce branch naming policy
#
# https://itnext.io/using-git-hooks-to-enforce-branch-naming-policy-ffd81fa01e5e

LC_ALL=C

top_level=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
head_name_file=${top_level}/.git/rebase-merge/head-name

if [[ -f ${head_name_file} ]]; then
    echo "Reading head name file ${head_name_file}"
    # local_branch=`basename $(<${head_name_file})`
    local_branch=$(<${head_name_file})
    local_branch=${local_branch#"refs/heads/"}
else
    echo "Parsing head"
    local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
fi

valid_branch_regex="^(main|((feature|bugfix|improvement|library|prerelease|refactoring|release|hotfix)\/[a-z0-9._-]+))$"

message="There is something wrong with your branch name $local_branch. \
Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract: $valid_branch_regex. \
Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."
```

This worked in the past, but now despite the branch name conforming to the policy, the commit fails.  I am currently trying to rebase a feature branch onto the head of the main branch.  The problem seems to be that the directory

```
${top_level}/.git/rebase-merge
```

does not exist.  However the following directory does:

```
${top_level}/.git/rebase-apply
```

How do I know which directory to expect?  Can I just check that one or the other exists?  Or is there maybe a better way of implementing such a policy?

Comment: *How do I know which directory to expect?* You don't; this changes from release to release. Don't use this method. Unfortunately: *Or is there maybe a better way of implementing such a policy?* There isn't really, which is why the hook you found uses this method. Git needs a better `git status --porcelain=v2` so that it can tell you about ongoing rebase here.

Comment: Ok, but as a nasty hack in the meantime, it sounds like I could just try both directories. It does however seem odd that is so difficult just to get ```head-name``` programmatically.

Comment: Yes, the nasty hack is pretty much what you're stuck with. Note that it fails on added worktrees (from `git worktree add`).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I hadn't come across worktrees before, but now I have, it seems like I would want to use them (I never really warmed to the whole stashing business). Oh well, maybe I'll just ditch the branch name policy enforcement.  It pretty much applies only to me anyway :-)

Comment: Yes, whatever the question is, `git stash` is probably the wrong answer.  Added worktrees are great, though they still have the occasional rough edge (it wasn't until fairly recently that most Git commands learned to check other worktrees for "actively checked out branches" for instance, and between 2.5 and 2.15 there was a terrible bug in added worktrees vs `git gc`).